# Exporting a function on typescript "declaration or statement expected"

Tags: typescript

I realize this is really simple but typescript seems to have changed a lot in the last years and i just cant get this done with previous answers i found here on stack overflow.

```
let myfunction = something that returns a function

export myfunction;
```

I get an error "declaration or statement expected"

How can i export a function from a really simple ts file to be able to use the function in another ts file?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

It seems that

```
let myfunction = something that returns a function
export {myfunction};
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 49):

Use

```
export default myfunction
```

if you only have this function to export from this file. Otherwise use

```
export { myfunction, <other exports> }
```

to export `myfunction` along with other types to export

Answer (score 1):

You can call a `function` or instantiate a `class` from another file using  modular top-level `import` and `export` declarations.

**file1.ts**

```
// This file is an external module because it contains a top-level 'export'
export function foo() {
    console.log('hello');
}
export class bar { }
```

**file2.ts**

```
// This file is also an external module because it has an 'import' declaration
import f1 = module('file1');
f1.foo();
var b = new f1.bar();
```

Comment: Thanks!, how would this work if i cant declare the function on the spot? in my case the function i wanted to export is returned by running another function.